# Differentiable function and tangent line

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

> **a.** Prove that differentiable function $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$ and its tangent line $T(x)$ at $a$ satisfies $|f(x) - T(x)|\le C|x-a|$ where $C=\sup\limits_{a\le y \le x}|f'(y) -f'(a)|$.

No idea! I am guessing using mean value theorem: $$\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=f'(c)$$

> **b.** If $f$ is $C^2$, refine this statement to: $$|f(x) -T(x)| \leq D|x-a|^2$$ where $D = \sup\limits_{a\le y \le x}|f''(y)|$.

Some useful facts:

$T(x) = f(x_0)+f'(x_0)\cdot(x-x_0)$

Comment: This is kind of bad notation. Fix a particular x. Consider the tangent $T_x(y)$. What does the mean value theorem tell you about $f(y) - T_x(y)$ on the interval $[a,b]$.

Comment: In the second inequality we have $|f(x)-T(x)|\leq \frac{D}{2}(x-a)^2$.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I have the feeling that thay have only seen the mean value theorem so far, and that haven't applied it yet to get Taylor-Lagrange. Maybe that's why $D$ instead of $D/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce the function 
$$
g(x):=f(x)-T(x)=f(x)-f(a)-(x-a)f'(a).
$$
Then note it has the same differentiability properties as $f$, with $g(a)=0$, $g'(x)=f'(x)-f'(a)$, $g'(a)=0$ , and $g''(x)=f''(x)$.

Also note that we only need $f$ twice differentiable on $(a,b)$ to get b.

a. Apply the mean value theorem to $g$ on $[a,x]$. This gives $y_x\in(a,x)$ such that $$g(x)=g(x)-g(a)=g'(y_x)(x-a).$$ The result follows.

b. Apply the mean value theorem to $g'$ on $[a,y_x]$. T yields $z_x$ in $(a,y_x)\subseteq[a,x]$ such that $$g'(y_x)=g'(y_x)-g'(a)=g''(z_x)(x-a).$$ Hence $g(x)=g''(z_x)(x-a)^2$ and the result follows.

Comment: Why is g'(y$_x) <= $$C=\sup\limits_{a\le y \le x}|f'(y) -f'(a)|$?

Comment: @maria Because $g'(y_x)=f'(y_x)-f'(a)$ and $a<y_x<x$. So $|g'(y_x)|\leq \sup_{a\leq y\leq x}|f'(y)-f'(a)|$.

Answer (score 5):

1. We apply the Taylor-Lagrange formula to $f$ with the first  order : there's $\alpha\in(a,x)$ such that
   $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(\alpha)$$
   so we find the first result
   $$|f(x)-T(x)|=(x-a)|f'(\alpha)-f'(a)|\leq(x-a)\sup_{a\leq y\leq x}|f'(y)-f'(a)|$$
2. We apply the Taylor-Lagrange formula to $f$ with the second order: there's $\alpha\in(a,x)$ such that
   $$f(x)=f(a)+(x-a)f'(a)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}f''(\alpha)=T(x)+\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}f''(\alpha),$$
   so we find the second result
   $$|f(x)-T(x)|=\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}|f''(\alpha)|\leq\frac{(x-a)^2}{2!}\sup_{a\leq y\leq x}|f''(y)|. $$

Comment: Nice and optimal answer, +1. Hopefully they have seen Taylor-Lagrange. Otherwise, there is still my lower tech answer.

Answer (score 1):

We have $f(x)=\int_a^x f'(t)dt+f(a)$ and $T(x)=f'(a)(x-a)+f(a)$. Thus
$$\begin{align}
\frac{|f(x)-T(x)|}{|x-a|} &=\frac{\left|\int_a^xf'(t)dt-f'(a)(x-a)\right|}{|x-a|}\\
&=\left|\int_a^x\frac{f'(t)-f'(a)}{x-a}dt\right|\\
&\leq \int_a^x\left|\frac{f'(t)-f'(a)}{x-a}\right|dt\\
&\leq \int_a^x\frac{C}{x-a}dt=C
\end{align}$$
so $|f(x)-T(x)|\leq C|x-a|$.

**Edit:** As julien points out, this only works for *continuously* differentiable functions. His answer is correct in general.

Comment: The OP did not assume $f$ to be $C^1$ in a. So I guess you can't use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @julien The form of the fundamental theorem of calculus I gave holds for all differentiable functions, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part).

Comment: It requires $f'$ to be Riemann-integrable. Is every derivative Riemann-integrable? If so, I have overlooked something deep my whole life...

Comment: Here is an example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volterra's_function

Comment: @julien Hmm. Doesn't the result hold if we use Lebesgue integration, however?

Comment: I think julien's answer is in the right direction, since I only covered differentiability. We havent covered integration yet.

Comment: Ok, I think this is the wild counterexample we need: the [Cantor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function). It is continuous, differentiable a.e. with zero derivative. But it is not constant. So the FTC does not hold.

Comment: @julien But it's not differentiable everywhere.

Comment: My first idea was the best example. Take $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ on $\mathbb{R}^*$ and extend it continuously by $0$ at $0$. This function is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ (in particular $f'(0)=0$, but that's where the problem is). In particular $\int_0^1f'$ does not exist, whether you talk about Riemann, Lebesgue, or even improper integral. Indeed, $f'(x)=2x\sin(1/x^2)-\frac{2}{x}\cos(1/x^2)$ for every $x\neq 0$. The first part is continuous, so $\int_0^1f'$ is of the same nature as $\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\cos(1/x^2)dx$. This diverges for Riemann, Lebesgue, and improper integrals.

Comment: @julien Ah, thank you for this example.

Comment: You're most welcome. Obviously, I needed to think about this to refresh my vague memories. Even though it does not really answer the question we were considering, I find the Cantor function a pretty interesting one.

Comment: @julien Oh it definitely is. In the same vein, are you familiar with Minkowski's ? function?

Comment: No I was not. Thanks for mentioning it. If [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski's_question_mark_function) is what you mean, that's another interesting case.